# Grails - Tika Content manipulation

Tags: grails, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse `.docx` file into `xml`. I can parse it and render the `xml` into a separate page. But what I really want is to display `<body>` only in a `template`, no `metadata`. How can I do this? I tried using `BodyContentHandler` but it got rid of `xml tags`.

Thank you.

**EDIT**

I had a simpler code in `controller` but I messed it up. This was what I had before. I'm getting the file from my `temp` folder and sending it to my `tikaService` (I copied the service from [GitHub](https://github.com/dewarim/tikaParser/blob/master/grails-app/services/tikaParser/TikaService.groovy).)

`Controller`

```
def parse(Document documentInstance) {
    def file = new File(documentInstance.fullPath)
    def result = tikaService.parseFile(file)
    render(view:"parse", text: result, contentType: "text/xml", encoding: "UTF-8")
}
```

`Service`

```
class TikaService {

    static transactional = false

    String parseFile(File file, TikaConfig tikaConfig, Metadata metadata){
        SAXTransformerFactory factory = SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance()
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler()
        handler.transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml")
        handler.transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes")

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()
        handler.result = new StreamResult(sw)

        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser(tikaConfig)
        ParseContext pc = new ParseContext()
        try {
            parser.parse(new FileInputStream(file), handler, metadata, pc)
            return sw.toString()
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to parse file ${file.absolutePath}", e)
            throw e
        }
    }

    String parseFile(File file){
        TikaConfig tikaConfig = new TikaConfig()
        Metadata tikaMeta = new Metadata()
        return parseFile(file, tikaConfig, tikaMeta)
    }
}
```

If I use the `render` I get

[image: this]

When I call the result from `parse.gsp` with `${result}` I get

[image: this]

I hope I'm making sense explaining this. Thank you.

**EDIT 2**

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="Revision-Number" content="0"/>
<meta name="Last-Printed" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="cp:revision" content="0"/>
<meta name="meta:print-date" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="meta:creation-date" content="2013-03-20T15:29:13Z"/>
<meta name="dcterms:modified" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="meta:save-date" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="dc:creator" content="ingo "/>
<meta name="Last-Modified" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="Author" content="ingo "/>
<meta name="dcterms:created" content="2013-03-20T15:29:13Z"/>
<meta name="date" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="X-Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser"/> 
<meta name="X-Parsed-By" content="org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.OfficeParser"/>
<meta name="modified" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<meta name="creator" content="ingo "/>
<meta name="Creation-Date" content="2013-03-20T15:29:13Z"/>
<meta name="meta:author" content="ingo "/>
<meta name="Content-Type" content="application/msword"/>
<meta name="Last-Save-Date" content="1601-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
<title/>
</head>
<body>
<p class="überschrift_1"><b>Tika Parser Test </b></p>
<p class="standard">This is a simple test document</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3**

Controller

```
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory
import javax.xml.transform.sax.TransformerHandler
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult

import org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext
import org.apache.tika.parser.Parser
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToXMLContentHandler
import org.apache.tika.sax.ToHTMLContentHandler

    def parse(Document documentInstance) {
        def file = new File(documentInstance.fullPath)
        BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(new ToHTMLContentHandler())
        AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser()
        FileInputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream(file)

        Metadata metadata = new Metadata()
        parser.parse(inputstream, handler, metadata)
    }
```

Error

`Namespace http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml not declared`

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, I've edited my post. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the XML as text so it can be copy-pasted?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa, I posted XML. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you combine ToXMLContentHandler and BodyContentHandler [as covered in the Apache Tika examples page](http://tika.apache.org/1.12/examples.html#Parsing_to_XHTML)?

Comment: @Gagravarr, I tried and I get this error. Cannot cast object '' with class 'org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler' to class 'java.net.ContentHandler'

Comment: You shouldn't be using any `java.net` stuff - check your imports

Comment: @Gagravarr, I've updated with imports. When I use `BodyContentHandler` I get the namespace error.

Comment: As per the example, can you try `ToXMLContentHandler` instead of `ToHTMLContentHandler` ?

Comment: @Gagravarr, I tried. I get the same error. I've found this discussion. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1774  It seems like the issue hasn't been resolved. I will continue to work around this. Thank you very much for your time, always.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks like the example given on Tika documentation is wrong:

> [link to the bug ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1774/)

Here is a fix to the problem:

> [link to solution](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1215?focusedCommentId=13869693&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13869693)

```
ToHTMLContentHandler toHtmlContentHandler = new ToHTMLContentHandler(outputStream, "UTF-8");
WriteOutContentHandler handler = new WriteOutContentHandler(toHtmlContentHandler, (int) 4000000);
ContentHandler bodyHandler = new BodyContentHandler(handler);
```

Hope this helps!